# Effectiveness of TRX System

Tags: exercise, training, strength-training

I am an early 20s fairly active person and volunteer firefighter. I am looking to increase strength and speed as an amateur athlete and be a more effective fireman. I have been lifting for 6 years now and I am now about 83 kg at 1.83m and can squat 225x3x10 comfortably and bench 185x3x10 comfortably as well. I am currently in a position where anything other than a home gym would be highly inconvenient. Would the TRX system be an effective way to meet these goals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's effective for what it does, but if you're looking for pure strength, it's not optimal.

It's great at working core, stabilizers, and bodyweight exercises, and IMO they're worth having.

If your goal is to increase raw strength, though, you'll need to lift heavy.

When I was faced with very limited space the Bowflex Selecttechs worked great, then I augmented that with a small set of heavy-ish kettlebells and two good sandbags. Since you have to lug gear around, a weight vest might also be nice.

All that said, I'm a pretty firm believer in bodyweight and functional exercises for jobs like that; while Navy SEALs lift heavy and hard, the core of their training is exactly like you see in the TV: pushups, situps and other core work, pullups, running, and carrying around heavy shit. It works.

Answer (score 1):

A TRX could be useful at home. It has a place as assistance work. However, I'd be cautious of making up a whole routine out of it. Wherever you currently lift (have have recorded your current rep PRs), in addition to some TRX at home, certainly isn't a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

There are some great exercises you can do with TRX.  In particular you can put your feet in the stirrups, bringing your weight more over your hands, and giving an unstable base, to do pressups, up and down planks etc..  Lots to do, but think you would still need the weights.  A great piece of kit to enhance a home workout though.